# How do I create a pty without a shell?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, python, tmux

Backstory: I have a CLI Python application. I want to be able to debug it without interfering with the CLI of the main application. The Python debugger allows you to specify an alternative stdin/stdout for the debugger.

I opened a new pane in tmux, and noted down the filename of the pty (/dev/pts/47). I then opened that pty file for reading and writing in Python. This seemed to be going in the right direction. The tmux pane showed some output from the Python debugger and responded to some of the letters I typed, but not all. I assume the problem is that bash is still running in the pty, and some of my input is going to bash, other input is going to Python, depending on which program reads from the pty first.

Is there a way to have tmux/screen/some other application create a pty, but not start a shell so another application can take over the slave side of the pty? Is this likely to work?

Is there another more appropriate way to have a program open a second CLI interface?

(An alternative that I tried is using mkfifo to create two named pipes and then `cat >/tmp/pipe_stdin | cat </tmp/pipe_stdout`. This worked but was line-buffered, so line editing doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly (I have no experience with debugging Python) it seems at first glance that the easiest approach would be to use 2 shell windows.
Run the debugger (with the application to debug) in one of them and redirect the debugger input/output to the 2nd one.
You can then control the debugger and observe its output in the 2nd shell without affected the output in the 1st one.

Comment: That's what I'm trying. But how? I found another way to make bash stop interfering, and that's to use sleep. But is there a way to just not have bash at all? Just a pty without shell?

Comment: Mmmhh... As I said, I'm not familiar with Python debugging. In all languages that I work with you essentially run the program "as usual" and run the debugger in a different terminal/gui as a separate process. From within the debugger you then "attach" to the program to be debugged, so the problem never comes up.

Comment: No, the Python debugger runs in the same process.

Comment: @FrederikVds In that case sleeping/suspending the shell holding the pty is probably the easiest option. Or having it run a do-nothing command like a "tail-f" on a file that doesn't change.